# Shuffling an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I know this has been answered before but none of the answers works for me. Or I don't know hot to implement them.
I have a `NSMutableArray` like this.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)tasks {
   tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@0 ,@1 ,@2 , @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13 ,@14 ,@15 ,@16 ,@17 ,@18 ,@19 ,@20 ,@21 ,@22 ,nil];
    return tasks;
}
```

and when i try to shuffle it like that

```
-(void)shuffle {
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; ++i) {
        int r = (random() % 23);
        [tasks exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:r];
    }
}
```

nothing happens. What should I do? Or how should I call it?

**EDIT i have a new code with method from gamekit but still nothing.**

[this is an error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f7QM.png)

**This is my .h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Accounts/Accounts.h"
@import GameKit;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController {


    IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    IBOutlet UITextView *description;

    NSArray *tasks;
    NSArray *shuffledTasks;

}





- (IBAction)random:(id)sender;



@end
```

**And this is my .m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@import GameKit;


@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {

    tasks = @[@0, @1, @2,  @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22];

    [self shuffle];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

NSInteger text;
int x=0;
int z=9999;


-(void)shuffle
{
  shuffledTasks = [[GKRandomSource sharedRandom] arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray:tasks];
    }


-(void)reset{
    if (x>22) {
        x=0;
        [self shuffle];
    }
}


- (IBAction)random:(id)sender {

    text = [[shuffledTasks objectAtIndex:x] integerValue];
    x++;


        switch (text) {


            case 0:
                //something
                z=0;

                [self reset];
                break;

            case 1:
                //something
                z=1;
                [self reset];
                break;

            case 2:
                //something
                z=2;
                [self reset];
                break;

            case 3:
                //something
                z=3;
                [self reset];
                break;

            case 4:
                //something
                z=4;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 5:
                //something
                z=5;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 6:
                //something
                z=6;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 7:
                //something
                z=7;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 8:
                //something
                z=8;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 9:
                //something
                z=9;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 10:
                //something
                z=10;
                [self reset];
                break;

            case 11:
                //something
                z=11;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 12:
                //something
                z=12;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 13:
                //something
                z=13;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 14:
                //something
                z=14;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 15:
                //something
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 16:
                //something
                z=16;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 17:
                //something
                z=17;
                [self reset];
                break;
            case 18:

                 //something

                z=18;
                [self reset];
                break;

            case 19:

                //something

                z=19;
                [self reset];
                break;

            case 20:

                //something

                z=20;
                [self reset];
                break;

            case 21:

                //something

                z=21;
                [self reset];
                break;

            case 22:

                //something

                z=22;
                [self reset];
                break;

            default:
            break;

        }  }



- (void)dealloc {
    [bannerView release];
    [cube1 release];
    [cube2 release];
    [super dealloc];
}
    @end
```

Comment: Where/how do you define tasks variable? and when do you call tasks method?

Comment: Tasks variable is defined in .h `NSMutableArray *tasks;` and I call it here:  `- (IBAction)random:(id)sender {
    text = [[self.tasks objectAtIndex:x] integerValue];` but that works. What does not work is the shuffle. Which I call likte this `[self shuffle];`

Comment: Make sure you call self.tasks (or [self tasks]) before calling [self shuffle]

Comment: I did an Edit with new code. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Why manually shuffle?  There is a method in the GameKit framework (available if you are targeting iOS 9 and above) to automatically shuffle objects in an array for you:

```
@import GameKit;

// ...

NSArray *tasks = @[@0, @1, @2,  @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22];

NSArray *shuffledTasks = [[GKRandomSource sharedRandom] arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray:tasks];
```

Comment: for iOS9 and above